# Why does Ruby have separate data types for Fixnums and Bignums, but not Strings and really long strings?

Tags: ruby

The first idea that comes to my mind is Ruby just allocates a big block of memory to strings -- but, of course, that seems very inefficient and therefore unlikely.

This doesn't really have a direct impact on my programming, but I'm very curious. Thank you!

Comment: `Fixnums` vs `Bignums` is not really comparable to little strings versus big strings. The latter would be more comparable to little arrays vs. big arrays, little hashes vs big hashes, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very crudely, `Fixnum`s represent numbers that the computer can store in a processor register and perform [basic arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) on. `Bignum`s are necessary because they represent numbers that by definition can **not** be stored in single registers, and therefore require "special" processing called [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) in order to perform arithmetic on them.

> In computer science, arbitrary-precision arithmetic, also called
>   bignum arithmetic [...] indicates that calculations are performed on
>   numbers whose digits of precision are limited only by the available
>   memory of the host system. This contrasts with the faster
>   fixed-precision arithmetic found in most arithmetic logic unit (ALU)
>   hardware, which typically offers between 8 and 64 bits of precision.

With strings, there is no such distinction. An arbitrarily long string never has arithmetic performed on it at the processor instruction level, so there's no reason to distinguish between a "short" string and a "long" string.

In regards to memory:

(Small) numbers can be manipulated directly as actual binary CPU instructions because they fit entirely into a single CPU memory address (called a register.)

Neither (big) numbers nor strings can because they overflow a processor's "number of bits." (This is what's meant by a "64-bit processor": A single numeric value can be represented and manipulated up to 64-bits of precision.)

Strings are allocated in memory as a series of numbers that represent characters (with different numbers representing different characters depending on the chosen encoding, such as UTF-8 or ASCII) and they span across multiple memory locations. The strings are never fed through CPU as **atomic** units though, whereas Fixnums are.

Bignums likewise can't be handled in the ALU because each value (potentially) takes up more memory than what is available in a single CPU register, so a separate package that defines the necessary mathematical operations to break down very large numbers, perform arithmetic on the smaller parts using the ALU and composite the individual answers together has to be written separately.

Comment: Interesting! But how does memory allocation work? My understanding of Fixnums and Bignums is that they have to be specified because Ruby allocates different amounts of memory to them from the get-go, and that determines how "big" the numbers can be. Why are numbers different from strings? I imagine this is a really big question, so if there isn't some succinct dumbed-down answer, no worries. :)

Comment: Fixnums are transparently upgraded into Bignums when they become large enough. Bignums are much slower than Fixnums, so Ruby wants to stay with Fixnums when possible. You should read up on how CPUs (or more accurately, the ALU) do arithmetic; it should be enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

In a way small strings are treated differently: no additional memory is allocated.
All basic Objects take 40 bytes. These bytes are sufficient to hold some data - for strings it's about 24 chars. For longer strings more memory is allocated, chunk-wise.

```
require 'objspace'

p ObjectSpace.memsize_of([]) # => 40
p ObjectSpace.memsize_of({}) # => 40
puts
str = ""
res = 10.times.map do
  str << "a"*10
  ObjectSpace.memsize_of(str)
end
p res #=> [40, 40, 87, 87, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 225]
```

Comment: That's interesting. Do you know if that applies to objects generally (e.g., small arrays, hashes, etc.)? If so, I could tweet three small objects at a time.

Answer (score 1):

`Fixnum`:

> Holds Integer values that can be represented in a native machine word
>   (minus 1 bit).

(from [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html))

This means that a integer that is a `Fixnum` on one computer might be a `Bignum` on another since it has to do with the computer's architecture. Ruby makes this conversion because it is more efficient to work with a `Fixnum` if possible.

Strings don't have this concept because strings in `c` (ruby is implemented in `c`) are represented by arrays of characters, so they can be arbitrarily long (within the memory available to the program).

Answer (score 0):

To be nit-picky: There are smaller and larger strings in Ruby. But they are both implemented in the same `String` class. There is a [long article](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/4/never-create-ruby-strings-longer-than-23-characters) that explains that Ruby optimizes strings with 23 chars or less and is significat slower when it deals with longer strings:

http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/1/4/never-create-ruby-strings-longer-than-23-characters

Comment: The same thing is true for `Float`s on YARV on 64 bit. So called *flonums* are used when the value fits into 62 bits without loss of precision and accuracy. Honestly, `Fixnum`s could have been implemented the same way, as a transparent optimization, a private internal implementation detail that isn't exposed to the programmer. It works for flonums in YARV, for `String`s in YARV, for small `Array`s in Rubinius (I think) and so forth, it could work just as well for `Integer`s.